# How can you select a specific range and a pivot table together in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Good Day,

I am trying to select this range, and well the code seems to process through, but when I get to my `if rng is nothing then` it does not grab the range. I've been stuck on this for awhile and any thoughts would help. This is also a snippet of the code, but I just assumed this was the most important part.

Note I have to keep this condition, because this section of code will always be called, and if it's empty, it will skip and run the next line. So I cannot just do a `select.`Again, any thoughts, help would be much appreciated! Ask me any questions if not clear. Thank you so much.

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set srng = Sheets("Email Template").PivotTables("PivotTable5")
    Set rng = Sheets("Email Template").Range("B3:J13" & srng)
    Set DDT = Worksheets("Email Template").Range("X2")
    Set Teamail = Worksheets("Email Template").Range("X3")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is get the range of the pivot table then if you want to set rng to refer to both B3:J13 and srng use Union.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim srng As Range
Dim DDT As Range
Dim Teamail As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

    Set srng = Sheets("Email Template").PivotTables("PivotTable5").TableRange1
    Set rng = Union(Sheets("Email Template").Range("B3:J13"), srng)
    Set DDT = Worksheets("Email Template").Range("X2")
    Set Teamail = Worksheets("Email Template").Range("X3")

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

P.S. It's not clear which part of the pivot table you want, I've used DataBodyRange but you could use TableRange1 to get the entire table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I still receive the error, thoughts?

Comment: I've edited my reply - your code (and my original code) was returning the actual pivot table, not it's range.

Comment: Hi Norie, thanks for your help... but I'm still hitting the error statement.

Comment: Not sure what error statement you are referring to, do you mean the message box after the If statement? What happens if you remove On Error Resume Next?

Comment: Okay, so i commented the "On Error Resume Next" and now it is saying there is a "Data Mismatch" when I try passing this code. Set srng = Sheets("Email Template").PivotTables("PivotTable5").TableRange1.... so there must be a problem with this line of code

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the exact code I used.

Comment: THIS IS PERFECT! THANK YOU!